Is datadog gprc trace metric (trace.grpc.server.hits) reliable?
My application is built using Kotlin and Spring Boot, with the gRPC framework running on AWS EKS clusters with datadog agent installed. We utilize Datadog APM to monitor the performance of our system. I am currently investigating the total number of requests for certain APIs in our service by examining the trace.grpc.server.hits metric. However, I’ve noticed that the total request hits reported by this metric are lower than the actual number of requests received. Does datadog have any metrics to monitor whether the datapoints have been dropped?
Debugging Process:

I have verified that our trace metrics are not sampled.
I have verified that the actual number of requests from logs and trace metrics(trace.grpc.server.hits) is missing the datapoints.

